# Java Scanner strange behavior

Tags: java

I have a java scanner and two loops to handle user input, However it throws an `NoSuchElement` exception the second it hits the first loop with out asking for any input from the user.

```
Scanner Guess_input = new Scanner( System.in );


    while (guess > 0){
        failure = true;
        while(failure)
        {

            System.out.println("Please input");
            try
            {
                if (Guess_input.nextLine().length() == 1 && guesses.size() >= 1) {
                    guesses.add(Guess_input.nextLine());
                    System.out.println("You guessed" + guesses.get(guesses.size()) + "");
                }
                else if (Guess_input.nextLine().length() == 0) {
                    System.err.println("ERROR:");
                    Guess_input.nextLine();   //Clean Buffer
                    failure = true;
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.err.println("ERROR");
                    Guess_input.nextLine();   //Clean Buffer
                    failure = true;
                }
            }   
            catch(InputMismatchException ime)

            {
                System.err.println("error");
            }
            finally
            {
                Guess_input.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `failure` boolean variable is never equal to `false`, so you'll have an infinite inner loop.

Comment: Your NoSuchElement exception is masking a lot of other problems by the way. For instance the `guess` variable never gets decremented so the outer loop will run forever, same thing with the inner loop as @Bernard pointed out. Also as one of the answers mentions your try/catch block is at the wrong level. The try should be wrapping the entire outer loop so that you don't close the Scanner until you're done with your processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the java documentation, when using the `next()` method of the `Scanner` class, you'll get

```
NoSuchElementException - if no such tokens are available
```

Whenever you call the `nextLine()` method, you are supposed to enter a `String`. You should first store the result of `nextLine()` in local variable unless that's what you want.

Another problem is that your `try catch finally` is done in your `while loop`. It means that for each iteration, your `finally` bloc will be executed everytime, so you'll think that there is an exception, while might be none. Apply these changes

```
try {
   while (guess > 0) {
       while (.....) {
           .....
       }
   }
} catch (...){
   ....
  }
finally{ .... }
```

Comment: Even if I create a string, store Guess_input.nextLine(); in it i get the exception before i get a chance to input anything

`working = Guess_input.nextLine();`

This line errors...

Answer (score 1):

The errant statement is `guesses.get(guesses.size())`. In Java lists use zero-based indexes, i.e. the index of the first element is always 0 and the last element is size - 1. By definition the size of a list is an invalid index.

You probably should just hold the next line in its own variable before adding it to the list so that your sysout statement can just reference the variable instead of pulling the value back out of the list. But the easy solution is to just change the code to `guesses.get(guesses.size() - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You're calling guesses.nextLine() way too many times. Every call to nextLine() will block the app and expect input. Furthermore, theres other issues to worry about there... like other people pointed out.

I'll stick to the scanner though.